# How can I stretch the header across the whole screen with no white spaces

Tags: html, css

I have a background image also and I would like to have the header stretched across the whole screen and also implement the nav bar into the header( I have solved the nav bar in the header problem). I have also searched and tried all of the examples here to no avail. for example like this: http://www.projectseven.com/

my html code is this:

```
<!DOCtype html>
<html>
<head>
<title>Adventist Youth's Empowerment</title>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="mainstyle.css" text="style/css">
<head>
<div id="header">
<nav>
<nav id="nav_bar_center">
<ul>
    <li><a href="Home.html">Home</a></li>
    <li><a href="Main.html">Main</a></li>
    <li><a href="Aboutus.html">About Us</a></li>
    <li><a href="Contactus.html">Contact US</a></li>
    <li><a href="form.html">Form</a></li>
    <li><a href="Pictures.html">Pictures</a></li>
</ul>
</nav>
</nav>
</div>
</head>
```

my css code is this:

```
body {
background-repeat:
background-size: 100%;
background-image: url(Images/background%20image5.jpg);
background-position: fixed;
}

#content {
font-family: Georgia, "Times New Roman", Times, serif;
font-size: 18px;
font-style: normal;
line-height: normal;
font-weight: normal;
font-variant: small-caps;
text-transform: none;
color: #000000;
}
nav {
width: 100%;
height: 33px;
background-image:url(Images/navbar.gif);
background-repeat:repeat;
}
#nav_bar_center {
width: 900px;
margin-left:auto;
margin-right:auto;
}

nav ul{
list-style:none;
}
nav a {
display:inline;
float:left;
text-decoration:none;
color:#FFF;
font:"Times New Roman", Times, serif;
font-size:18px;
font-weight:bold;
line-height: 33px;
padding-left: 25px;
padding-right: 25px;
padding-bottom: 5px;

}
nav a:hover {
background-image:url(Images/navbgr.gif);
height: 28px;
}
#header {
width: 100%;
background-image:url(Images/header.gif);
}
```

Comment: That's *not* how you build an HTML page. Content of your page go into the `body` tag, **not** in the `head` tag.

Comment: I know how to build a HTML page. The reason why there is content in the head is because I want the nav bar in the header on top of the page. that is the question i asked and this is an example!

Comment: solved the nav bar in the header problem now I want to have the header stretched across the browser screen with no white spaces at the top and right and left side.

Comment: Your `<div id="header">` is empty, did you try putting your `<nav id="nav_bar_center">` code in that?

Comment: Apparently you *don't*. There is a difference between the HTML5 `header` element and the `head` element.

Comment: Question solved! my apologies, I thought by adding the content in the head I would get the content on top of the screen, but I was wrong. I will revert back to using the semantic mark up.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

HTML mark up is invalid, don't wrap you're `body` content in `head` tags instead use the, easy named: `<body></body>` tags to wrap you're page content. Also don't wrap the `nav` element in another `nav` tags.

The whitespace you were getting was because of browser default styling applied, you could use a reset stylesheet I recommend [Eric Mayer's](http://meyerweb.com/eric/tools/css/reset/). Or you could use this handy css statement.

```
* {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}
```

It effectively targets every element on the page and makes their margins and paddings 0.

---

You should instead use semantic markup for you're HTML.

```
<!DOCtype html>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <title>Adventist Youth's Empowerment</title>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="mainstyle.css" text="style/css">
    </head>
<body>
<header></header>
    <nav>
        <ul>
            <li><a href="Home.html">Home</a></li>
            <li><a href="Main.html">Main</a></li>
            <li><a href="Aboutus.html">About Us</a></li>
            <li><a href="Contactus.html">Contact US</a></li>
            <li><a href="form.html">Form</a></li>
            <li><a href="Pictures.html">Pictures</a></li>
        </ul>
    </nav>
</body>
</html>
```

Here I have also created a jsFiddle for the effect you wanted to achive located here: http://jsfiddle.net/5vdgr/

Comment: That solved my problem. And the only reason I put the content in the head tag as because I thought that would make the content appear on top  of the screen. I will not do that again, Thanks for the advice and answer.